# Running Maven release via bash or groovy scripts

Tags: bash, maven, groovy, maven-release-plugin

I'm wondering are there any example groovy or bash scripts out there for running a Maven release.

We run a mixture of mvn versions and release plugin commands as part of the release process.

Any example gmaven or bash scripts available to get me started.

Comment: What's the problem with *mvn release:prepare release:perform -B* ?

Comment: i want a single script to automate the entire release which includes mvn release:prepare release:perform -B, mvn versions update-parent, use latest version and update properties. I was hoping this would be possible via gmaven somehow?

Comment: Why do you need mvn versions update-parent ? If you already done **mvn -B release:prepare release:perform** this has already happened.

Comment: this version goals are run post release prepare/perform to update the trunk to the next SNAPSHOT version of the parent and dependencies. Ready for next iteration of development

Comment: @khmarbaise: That's not true for external parents. The release plugin does not update parents that are not contained in the reactor. It's a common case to perform `versions:update-parent` before the release to set the external parent to the last released version und `versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true` after release to set the external parent to Snapshot again.

Comment: @DarVar Where is the problem to simply but these maven steps you already mentioned in a bash script? I don't see any benefit using GMaven. If you release using Hudson/Jenkins you can define several maven commands in seperate executions in one Job.

Comment: What mixture do you run?

Comment: Simple google search: "mvn release script", gives this link: http://blog.lick-me.org/2011/01/automating-maven-releases/

Comment: https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-dev-tools/blob/master/xwiki-release-scripts/maven-release.sh

Comment: Although not really an answer (since the question is not very precise, but does mention maven and groovy, implying scripting maven builds...), maybe it's time to look at gradle? => http://www.gradle.org

Comment: Have you tried Jenkins. It's kind of doing things like a script (automated). Even if you have a script ready (which can be few lines), you'd need it someday on Jenkins.